# Newsfeed Everyone: Internal Error Code 55 for single Users

Tags: 2016, user-profile, newsfeed, distributedcache

Single user with issues in his Newsfeed - Everyone. For all other users "Everyone" works fine. User is approx. 6 months old.

[image]

> Message: SharePoint returned the following error: the operation failed
>   because the server could not access the distributed cache. Internal
>   type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException.
>   Internal error code 55. Contact your administrator for help in
>   resolving this problem.

There seems to be nothing special about this user. As we use OneDrive for Business and he has a lot of shared content in his OneDrive I hesitate deleting his profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a User Profile Service full sync to solve the issue.

This is only a solution for single users having this issue.

If you got all users affected check Central Administration - Service Applications - User Profile Service Application - Permissions (top bar) and give service account full access.